# When writing a paper should I describe the procedure thoroughly?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I have not written any article on a chemistry subject yet, and I want to use good practices from the start.

What I have noticed reading papers, is that a lot of times it is not specified the exact procedure that is followed in a reaction, for example by saying the exact tools that are used, or the parameters used in a technique, not even in supporting information documents.

At first I thought that some information was not really relevant, but as I read more articles I found more things like “*X product is centrifugated*” or “*Y is sonicated*”, without further detailing the exact procedure that was followed, the set parameters or even the devices that were used, which can obviously be very important for a given reaction.

My opinion would be that the more information the better and I think that by omitting that information you are wasting time and resources to any researcher that tries to replicate your experiment, as well as making it difficult to check the replicability of the procedure.

Then my question is, how far should I go in describing the procedure? Should I mention even which glassware I use for a given reaction? Maybe sometimes it is pretty obvious what should be used, but it is additional information that does not hurt to know and may be useful for obtaining the exact same results. However, it is as far as I have seen not a common practice and there must be a reason behind that.
Maybe omitting this information is preferable in articles as it uses less words and it avoids making articles excessively wrong, if that is the case, what about reports or thesis with a less restricting length limits?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I will assume that you are a student or at least not that experienced in experimental, wet lab chemistry based on your tags. If you are writing for fellow novices, the more descriptive the better. A good source is Organic Syntheses. http://www.orgsyn.org/

Comment: Usually chemists like to think they have an understanding as to what aspects of the reaction matter for reproducibility, and what aspects aren't (and can therefore be omitted). Some reactions are very forgiving; others less so. To an extent, that is something you gain through experience with the particular reaction you are reporting. But in general, people are more likely to appreciate extra detail than the other way round. Also, sometimes people find that they are quite wrong, and that some previously overlooked bit was actually crucial for reaction success :-)

Comment: In better journals, sometimes more detail is in the supporting information. I find most academic procedures shockingly poor in their descriptive detail and I'm not always sure if it's unintentional

Comment: @orthocresol I agree, as a new chemistry researcher I feel like I should write down every little step, as I'm not all so sure that even using a given glassware over another can really affect the reaction outcome, for example heat can distribute differently depending on the shape or the size of the container, which i know can be an important factor when synthesising things like nanoparticles, on the other hand, as a new researcher I see most of the papers lack this information, and I don't want to make the mistake of putting too much irrelevant information.

Comment: There can be too much detail. I always used a lot of detail in my papers, but once I started teaching and reading lab reports on a regular basis, I realized that my students like to write too much in their methods sections, often including what labels they put on each tube. But in general, I think you should assume that anyone reading your paper knows about as much as you knew about the topic, and you just need to give them enough detail to repeat your procedure. And I definitely went into more detail in my thesis than in my papers.

Comment: "Charles, it isn't necessary to tell us the incredibly obvious.
The merely obvious will do." -- Hawkeye Pierce, "Life Time" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following criterion in mind when you write a method in a paper: If you were reading this synthesis procedure from a book or a paper, *could you replicate it or not*? Do you feel anything is missing for proper duplication? When I review a methodology section of a papwe, I keep this criterion in mind: "Using this written information, can I reproduce his/her work?", otherwise I ask for more information.

Since you mentioned synthesis, a good sample procedure could be from *Organic Synthesis* http://www.orgsyn.org/

See how they write good procedures, and these methods are verified by independent person. Additionally, some journal put restrictions on word count, but still you want more details. For that, Supporting Information file exists on most good quality journals. I once saw someone even added pictures of their synthetic procedure/apparatus. Nobody will mind but it is not common.

*Odd cases*: Mentioning the source of glassware might be important *if* glassware surface were affecting the reaction. I "re-discovered" this only once. Sometimes the age of a solvents might affect the reaction. Tetrahydrofuran when used a solvent can have traces of peroxide which can show new unexpected products.

Now, there is a trend these days to intentionally hide some information so that competitor's cannot catch up with your work or write the method in a sloppy bare minimum way. This is really sinister but it happens and such practices must be curbed. Ayway scientists are not saints-they are human beings like everyone.